# Loading a specific part of JSON API data

Tags: javascript

I know this question has been asked before, but I have tried just about every way to get this to work, AJAX, JQUERY, trying to use p5.js and none seem to work.

All I want to do is open my api, parse the JSON data, and log the first_name element of the JSON data

I am willing to use other functions to achieve the API result.

```
var apiURL = 'url';

var request1 = new XMLHttpRequest();

request1.open('GET', apiURL, true);


request1.onload = function()
{
if (this.status === 200)
    {
       
    console.log(JSON.parse(request1.responseText));
        ting = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(request1.responseType));
        console.log(ting);
        console.log(ting.first_name);
        console.log(ting.first_name[0]);
    }
};

request1.send();
```

the API url is [https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-finder?domain=asana.com&first_name=Dustin&last_name=Moskovitz&api_key={API](https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-finder?domain=asana.com&first_name=Dustin&last_name=Moskovitz&api_key=%7BAPI) KEY}

the JSON data is

[JSON Gyazo](https://gyazo.com/49aa56e2cc3d193d64bb2a0d2392e7ca)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logs your first_name to the console using jQuery AJAX.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-finder?domain=asana.com&first_name=Dustin&last_name=Moskovitz&api_key={API_KEY}",
    type: 'GET',
  }).done(function(dataObj) {
        console.log(dataObj.data.first_name);
  }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + textStatus);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately still returning undefined, the JSON whole data gets returned fine but some reason I can't get any specific objects out of the JSON data logged. I have tried using FETCH api aswell but to no avail.

Comment: Can you try again, I made a small mistake that broke everything in the edit I made.
`}).done(function(data) {` should have been `}).done(function(dataObj) {`

Comment: My friend if this was a homosexual sauna I would give u a handy u have just saved me so much stress aha. Ill use AJAX for my future API calls now thanks man

Comment: Haha no problem dude! If you ever need to do an API call server-side (php) look into cURL.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, first_name is under obj.data.first_name not obj.first_name

```js
var apiURL = 'https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-finder?domain=asana.com&first_name=Dustin&last_name=Moskovitz&api_key=0409bb7315acf3ed037b22818e10fd51ff7be5e4';

var request1 = new XMLHttpRequest();

request1.open('GET', apiURL, true);


request1.onload = function()
{
if (this.status === 200)
    {

  var obj = JSON.parse(request1.responseText);
   
      console.log(obj.data.first_name)
    }
};

request1.send();
```